# What I Need To Use Adobe AIR To Develop For iPad?

Tags: flash, ipad, ios, adobe, air

I've recently got an iPad and I saw that Adobe AIR can be used to build native applications for the iPad and other iOS devices(I already own a iPod Touch 3g). Then my questions are:

- What are the needed tools to get this environment working at Windows?
- I use Aptana to develop my AIR applications, can I use it to compile the iPad apps too?
- There is any tutorial that will help me to configure and test the environment(better if at Aptana)?

PS: I don't care if I can't upload my applications to the App Store. Cydia is good for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're *suppose* to become a registered developer ($99/year) in order to install a mobile provisioning profile to test your work on the device, but luckily there are lots of crafty people in the world who will always find ways around that kind of foolishness.

this link was published back in May:  [How to use Adobe's iPhone Packager without an Apple Developer Subscription](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/)

i'm only testing this myself right now so i can't comment yet, but other recent comments on the thread state it's working on jailbroken devices.

you can package your AIR .ipa using the command line:  [Packager for iPhone Refresher](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html) (Step 4)

Comment: yup, totally works.  fun stuff!  but it's too bad AIR for iOS is really slow/choppy (currently).  oh well, there's always every other OS ;)